# Get online time in swift

Tags: swift, time

My app requires user to be online and am trying to get the server time even if user changes their date.  I found this code and it works only first time i run the app. Then the next time it freezes and i have to change the website. Every time i change the website it get the date and time right after that i keep getting the same exact time.

**Code:**

```
func getTimeFromServer(completionHandler:@escaping (_ getResDate: Date?) -> Void){
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {(data, response, error) in
        let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
        if let contentType = httpResponse!.allHeaderFields["Date"] as? String {
            //print(httpResponse)
            let dFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"
            let serverTime = dFormatter.date(from: contentType)
            completionHandler(serverTime)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Look up "NTP servers". They tell you the time.

Comment: I would use an NTP server, maybe use: https://github.com/instacart/TrueTime.swift

Comment: Agree that you should use NTP servers to get accurate time. But most likely the cause of your problem is that the HTTP response is getting cached.

Comment: i tried to make httpResponse: HTTPURLResponse? = nil
worked for 5 min and then froze again
how do i delete the chache

Answer (score 1):

It is still better to use an NTP server, but try using the following, which would ignore caching:

```
func getTimeFromServer(completionHandler:@escaping (_ getResDate: Date?) -> Void){
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 20)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {(data, response, error) in
        let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
        if let contentType = httpResponse!.allHeaderFields["Date"] as? String {
            //print(httpResponse)
            let dFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"
            let serverTime = dFormatter.date(from: contentType)
            completionHandler(serverTime)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: it worked but now taking much more time and sometimes am getting error httpResponse is nil
do you have a link to see how i do NTP server?
thank you

Comment: It will take much more time because you are ignoring the cache, so it needs to download the full response again. Try increasing the timeout. But really, as the others have said you should use an NTP server. It will be much faster. I was simply answering why it worked the first time.

Comment: after following NTP steps, i couldnt do it right i think am not understanding a step, but with your code you gave me by removing the cache it worked i just removed the time out interval, i dont need it since i just need time when i load page and when user click on btn, so i just call it when i need to get time, thanks for helping :-)